# Preloader and progress bar do not run after upload to server

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm using Flash Builder 4.5 to build a flash game. Everything is ok when I test in localhost. When I upload swf files to server, I use `FILE MANAGER` in host server to access the swf.

For example:

```
http://mysite.info:2222/CMD_FILE_MANAGER/domains/mysite.info/public_html/flash/Main.swf
```

All of them run normally from 1% to 100%, but when I access the swf in URL for example    `http://mysite.info/flash/Main.swf` then the preloader and progress bar always do not run, but the swf still loads.

However, when I upload files to free swf host like megaswf,  preloader and progress bar run normally.

I don't know how to find the solution for this problem. Please, help me!

Comment: How about the path to the preloader? Same path as Main? Also how about RWX permissions in your file manager what are they like?

Comment: What you are describing sound a lot like a server side configuration issue I encountered as well.
Try to follow the steps defined in my blog post about this:
http://dennisjaamann.com/blog/?p=157

Comment: This could also be a simple caching issue.  Make sure your browser cache is turned off so that the swf has to download fresh each time.  Also, are the preloader and the game in the same swf? If so, are you sure that the bulk of your content that you want to preload is not sitting on the first frame of your swf?  This would cause the preloader not to show until the entire first frame, with most of the assets in it, was downloaded too, which would mess up the preloader.  Anyway, just some thoughts. Good luck with it!

Comment: thanks all of you !!! I'll check my server's configuration